# sed: delete all but the last X lines of a file

Tags: sed

It can be done with other tools, but I am interested to know how can I delete all but the last X lines of the file with `sed`.

Comment: The hard way. Stick with the other tools.

Answer (score 11):

Basically you are emulating tail.  X = 20 in this example.  The following example will delete all but the last 20 lines:

```
sed -i -e :a -e '$q;N;21,$D;ba' filename
```

Explanation:

- The -e :a creates a label called a
- The next -e:

  - $q - quits and prints the pattern space if it is the last line
  - N - next line
  - 21,$D - executes the "D" command if the line# is >= 21 (21,$ = 21st line to $ which is the end of the file)
  - ba - branches to label 'a' which is the beginning of the script.

Comment: It works as tail, but I was not able to make it work in place (as the in the original question)

Comment: +1... BTW. It works with `-i` if you condense the two `-e` expressions into one. You can also use it by passing bash variable `$1` into it... `sed -i ':a;$q;N;'$(($1+1))',$D;ba' filename` ... but asking for `0` lines, will return 1 line.

Comment: @Peter.O That just blew my mind. Could you please explain this bit: `'$(($1+1))'` ??

Comment: with `$(($i+1))` you can calculate the amount of linesby a given variable `$i` ([bash-arithmetic-expansion](https://www.shell-tips.com/bash/math-arithmetic-calculation/#using-the-bash-arithmetic-expansion)

Comment: This command uses a lot of RAM if you try it on a large log-file (many GB)! and you'd need enough free memory or you get an error like: `sed: couldn't open temporary file /var/log/sedKrDiYy: Permission denied`

Answer (score 7):

`sed` is quite complex when it comes to task like this one. `tail`, `grep` or `awk` would make this a lot easier and should be used instead. That being said, it *is* possible.

The following solution is adapted from [sed and Multi-Line Search and Replace](http://austinmatzko.com/2008/04/26/sed-multi-line-search-and-replace/).

```
sed -ni '
    # if the first line copy the pattern to the hold buffer
    1h
    # if not the first line then append the pattern to the hold buffer
    1!H
    # if the last line then ...
    ${
            # copy from the hold to the pattern buffer
            g
            # delete current line if it is followed by at least X more lines
            # replace X-1 with the proper value
            s/.*\n\(\(.*\n\)\{X-1\}\)/\1/
            # print
            p
    }
' filename
```

Without the comments, it makes a nifty one-liner. If you want to eliminate, e.g., everything but the last ten lines, use this:

```
sed -ni '1h;1!H;${;g;s/.*\n\(\(.*\n\)\{9\}\)/\1/;p;}' filename
```

Comment: On non-GNU seds you need -e after -i.

Comment: Just like *phiz's* answer, this does not handle a request for `0` last lines... However, that is one of the reasons for the recommendation to use another tool.

Comment: This command also uses a lot of RAM if you try it on a large log-file (many GB)! and you'd need enough free memory or you get an error like: `sed: couldn't open temporary file /var/log/sedKrDiYy: Permission denied`. so you better use `F=your.file; X=20; head -n -$X $F > /tmp/tmpfile && mv /tmp/tmpfile $F`

Answer (score 2):

Based on the script in [section 4.13 of the sed manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#tail) you could do something like this:

```
n=10

(( n > 1 )) && script='1h; 2,'$n'{H;g;}; $q; 1,'$((n-1))'d; N; D'
(( n > 1 )) || script='$!d'

sed -i "$script" infile
```

Answer (score 1):

### tac|sed|tac>&&(mv||cat>)

Both of the following command snippets will effectively delete all but the very *last **5** lines* of `~/file1`. If you want to retain the *last **10** lines*, you can substitute: `|sed '1,5!d;'` with `|sed '1,10!d;'`, *and so  on*, as you see fit.

1. ```
   tac ~/"file1" |sed '1,5!d;' |tac >"/tmp/file2" &&mv  "/tmp/file2"  ~/"file1"
   ```
2. ```
   tac ~/"file1" |sed '1,5!d;' |tac >"/tmp/file2" &&cat "/tmp/file2" >~/"file1"
   ```